# ProgressOverlay vs ProgressBar Windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my Windows phone app,

I have a Coding4Fun progress Indicator in XAML.

```
<c4f:ProgressOverlay Canvas.ZIndex="1000" Background="Black" x:Name="progressOverlay" Opacity="0.9" d:IsLocked="True" d:IsHidden="False">
    <c4f:ProgressOverlay.Content>
        <StackPanel>
            <slToolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Foreground="White" IsIndeterminate="True" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="22" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Initialising UI ...</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </c4f:ProgressOverlay.Content>
</c4f:ProgressOverlay>
```

I invoke `progressOverlay.Show();` in `void page_Loaded()` event. Then I create more buttons in code. Then, I call `progressOverlay.Hide();`;  But, I didn't see progress bar at all. When the buttons were loading, there was no progress indicator, instead a black screen.

The exact setup, I replace with `SystemTray.ProgressIndicator`. It works fine. i.e. As soon as page is opened, progress bar appears, then buttons load, then this bar disappears.

What is wrong with the previous progress bar (I called that in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to run async)?

Simply, **"How can I display progress overlay, when UI thread is used for another resource intenstive process"**?

Comment: When your UI Thread is used for something, it won't be updating the UI in between, so you will just have a frozen screen and a bad user experience.

Comment: @KaiBrummund Exactly. It was a bad UI. So, what shall I do to display a progress overlay and at the same time load other elements?

Comment: Usually, loading a complete Screen full of UI Controls doesn't take very long. Even with complex list templates, etc.  Are you loading data as you are creating your controls? Can you move that loading to another thread? Can you separate you data logic from your control visualization logic? Why are you creating UI in code, not in Xaml? Just some questions to ask yourself. Otherwise: Provide more context. :)

Comment: I have a json having text and image paths. I deserialise it and create `liveTile` objects. Finally, I add these to a `Grid`. It takes time to load 10 such live Tiles. Moreover, I am deserialising from a `Task.Factory.StartNew();` and calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` from inside the function.

Comment: Could you add that Code to your question?

Comment: @KaiBrummund The code is http://pastebin.com/eVeGPGSP

Comment: You are new to c#, right? Why do you construct your tiles in code, instead of using a list with a data-template (or TemplateSelector, as you seem to have two tile-types)? Unless you are loading a really big chuck of data, I don't see anything on first view. Maybe its in your local:liveTile usercontrol.

Comment: I wanted to display a progress bar, then load the controls. I cant do that in XAML, that is why I use it in code. Regarding liveTile, it has four storyboards x 10 tiles, hence lot of threads on CPU and lots of memory